# going to www version of site url receives 404 on django site

Tags: django, django-views, cname

I can get to the route of my site without issues like this: http://example.com

When I go to http://www.example.com  I get a 404 error.

How can I handle going to www and delivering the user to the route of the site?

I don't think it is related, but here is my httpd.conf:

```
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi

<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIDaemonProcess example.com display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /example
    WSGIScriptAlias / /example/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>


Alias /static/ /example

<Directory /example>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIPythonPath /example

<Directory /example>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: I have some websites built with Django on a Webfaction server, and I had the opposite of this issue. It turned out not to be a problem with Django, but rather how Apache (on Webfaction's server) was configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change ALLOWED_HOSTS in the settings.py to something like this

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.example.com', 'example.com']

According to Django Documentation, ALLOWED_HOSTS defines

> A list of strings representing the host/domain names that this Django site can serve. This is a security measure to prevent an attacker from poisoning caches and triggering password reset emails with links to malicious hosts by submitting requests with a fake HTTP Host header, which is possible even under many seemingly-safe web server configurations.

For more [ALLOWED_HOSTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts)

Comment: A wrong `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting would return a 400 status code, not a 404.